# Enabling button if I write in TextField

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I am having some problems with enabling a button when you write something in a TextField.
I got it to disable if a there's nothing in the TextField but I can't make it to enable again when you write something in it.

I have something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUInteger textLength = [_Name.text length];
    [_doneButton setEnabled:(textLength > 0)];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if([textField.text length]>0){
    [doneButton setEnabled:YES];        

}
else{
 [doneButton setEnabled:NO ;
}
```

Hope this May be help you..

Comment: This needs to be placed in the `shouldChangeCaractersInRange:(NSRange)` Placing in `viewDidLoad` will only get called once when the page loads and then never again.

Comment: @SKM, I tried your code and it did not work. Should i add some more adjustments for this to work?

Comment: @Santiago, how did you make it work? Please let me know, Thank you.

Comment: This isn't the solution. When `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` gets called, the text isn't changed yet, hence the "should" part of the name. If you check the length of `[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]` it will work. But you should only do that check if you will return `YES`.

Answer (score 9):

Set delegate to the UITextField and create a method for text change in ViewDidLoad as follows.

```
[self.textFieldTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And add the method as follows.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == self.textFieldTemp) 
        self.buttonTemp.enabled = ([self.textFieldTemp.text length] > 0) ? YES : NO; }
```

Comment: This was the best solutions. Other answer don't work in some cases like when 1 character is entered. But this ones nails it.

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. Especially helpful if you have a number of UITextFields whose state may determine whether the button should be enabled i.e. username & password pair for example

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITextField` delegate method to enable your button again. When your `textField` characters are changed,  delegate method will be called, enable your button here.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     _doneButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Nope doesn't changes anything, I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Put the lines in textfield delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

It'll work then. This method is called every time you input a character in textfield. But ViewDidLoad is called only when the viewcontroller is loaded.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions will enable and disable your button according the text in your textfield

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     _doneButton.enabled = YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if([textField.text length]>0){
   [doneButton setEnabled:YES];        
}
else{
 [doneButton setEnabled:NO ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates of UITextField to enable and disable the button like this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
{
if (textField.text.length!=0)
{
yourButton.enabled = YES;
}
else
{
yourButton.enabled = NO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I used didn't use the delegates at all. I created this method in the controller class:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.doneButton.enabled = ([self.Name.text length] > 0) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Then, in the Interface Builder, I set the text field "Editing Changed" action to target the new method. Then, similar to @Paramasivan Samuttiram, I added an extra call to it in the `viewDidLoad:`.

```
[self textFieldChanged:self.Name];
```

That part allows the button to be in the correct state initially.